# Combine vlookup and match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet1!$A$2:$AO$8347,34+MATCH(9^99,Sheet1!AI2:AO2,1),FALSE)
```

Ideally this would find `A3` in `sheet1` and report the value in the right most spread between `AI` and `AO` and add `34` to this.

My problem is I need the row from the lookup_array to be the row found in `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: FYI: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=excel+index+match+vlookup

Comment: Yes the values are numeric, and the formula will currently return the rightmost value of AI#:AO# (#=2 for this example) instead of the right most value of that column ranges correlating to the vlookup row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need an indirect this way, but something like this would work -

```
=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,INDIRECT("Sheet1!AI"&(MATCH(A3,Sheet1!$A:A,0)&":AO")&(MATCH(A3,Sheet1!$A:A,0))))+34
```

Obviously your `match` will find the row that you're searching for.

Combine that row with an `indirect` with the specified columns will give you the range you're looking in.

The `lookup` will find the right-most value in that range

Then you add 34. This won't handle errors though.

Comment: Trying this now, I don't think its getting it. I'll lookup what the functions here mean though because I am naive on this subject.

Comment: Just to make sure my intention is clear: I want to find A3 in the data on sheet1, determine its row, and then report the right most value for that row in sheet1 between columns AI and AO.

Comment: Still getting #N/A A3 is a code that is in the cell A3 on sheet2 (where I am inserting the formula) and one of a list of thousands on Sheet1 column A

Comment: @Charlie try it now. If you're getting N/A then there's no match. Try `=match(A3,Sheet1!A:A,0` and see what you get with that

Comment: Oh sweet this is getting close! I do get the row number when using the above formula. However its not giving me the correct value (although it is returning a value now. In particular numbers that are not on the sheet1 are still giving values (about 10% should give NA)

Comment: again to clarify, the match formula is giving me the correct row number, the attached formula above is still off somewhere

Comment: @Charlie add `0` to your matches, see above.

Comment: GOT IT! Just added exact match to the matches! THANK YOU SO MUCH!